# Continuity of function from function space, $\Phi : C[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\Phi(f) = \inf\{t \geq 0: f(t) \leq u\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $u\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\Phi : C[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by
$$\Phi(f) = \inf\{t\geq0 : f(t)\leq u\}$$  Let metric over $C[0,\infty)$ be
$$\|f\|=\|f\|_\infty \wedge 1 = \min\{\sup\{|f(x)|: x \in [0, \infty)\}, 1\}$$
The metric over $\mathbb{R}$ is the usual Euclidean metric. **Is $\Phi$ a continuous map?**

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: I am not actually sure whether the proposition is correct. I just wonder if it is! I tried sequence method!

Comment: $\|\cdot\|$ is not a norm, if $f(x)=1/3$ and $\alpha =2$, then $\|\alpha f\| \neq \alpha \|f\|$.

Comment: It is not a norm. It is a metric. I suppose i should use a different notation.

Comment: I realise that there was a following problem in the definition of $\Phi$. What will happen if the function is always greater that $u$? Thus I would like to change the problem to the following:

 1. If a sequence of functions $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the given metric, then whether $\Phi(f_n)$ will converge to $\Phi(f)$, [if the $f_n$'s and $f$ satisfy the definition required \Phi.]
 2. Considering the infimum of empty sets to be infinity, is it true that $\Phi(f_n)$ converges to $\Phi(f)$ always?

Comment: Modifying a question in the comments section is bad practice on this site. I suggest that you accept your own answer, and then ask the new question that you really wanted to ask in a new post.

Comment: Actually the new question is also answered in the solution which I have posted below. So there is no point in uploading now, but I will bear your advice in mind next time while posting. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The proposition is not true. First of all the function is not well defined for functions which are always greater than $u$.

In the comments section I modified the problem.

If you take the constant functions
$f_{n}(t)= u+ 1/n,  f(t)=u,$   for all $t\in[0,\infty)$, then $f_{n}$'s converge to $f$, but $\Phi(f_{n})=+\infty$ for all $n$, while $\Phi(f)=0.$
This serves as a nice counterexample.